# Do we need corrective shape for shoulder deformation when arm stretch?

Tags: modeling, rigid-body-simulation, topology, rigidbody

I am having problem with shoulder deformation.  I understand that I can use corrective shape.  But, I wonder if we really need too. Any tip would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you can't improve the rigging weight on this part of your mesh?

Comment: I can improve to a certain extend with weight paint.  Still, it does not reach the "natural look".  So, I'm wondering if there is anyone who archieve good result without corrective shape.

Comment: I think you should try to improve the rigging and I'm not sure but I wonder if the topology is not part of the problem as well

Comment: possible... I may resolve to straw shoulder and arm lol. Would you have any topology and work?

Comment: could you please share your file (remove the non important part if you want)? I could test: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I try using blend exchange but it keeps saying "error uploading"

Comment: it needs to be a blend file and once you've dropped the file you must put the address of this page in the dedicated field (Enter the URL...), then Upload

Comment: Yea~ I think I did those.  Still cant seem to get it to work.  I must be doing something wrong.  I will be looking for solution on the blend exchange.  It seems easy to use too.  I will use pasteall for now:  http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51665

Comment: I can't read your file, I don't know why

Comment: let me try again:  http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51666   ->> from this link.. i have to download 2 times before getting the mesh.   dont know what is up lol

Comment: ok it works now

Comment: Thx for your helps.

Comment: From my experience you would need quite a few additional bones to use only weights. Shapekeys are much easier to handle in this case.

Comment: there are some things I don't understand in your armature, why there are several overlaying bones, why their deform option is deactivated, also I would make a character with the arms horizontal (in T) so that you can easily move the arms up and down without too many mesh deformations, it would help a lot in my opinion, maybe avoid any shapekey works

Comment: There are hiden bones.  I hide them so the deformation is visible > Leander

Comment: I just testing separating the fk ik and deforming bones.  In regards to T poseture, I can also do that.  its just the original sketch has the hands down lol.  But your suggestion about T-pose base mesh make good sense.  Still, I am very interestd in a non-shapekey solution for the mesh as is.  thx.

Comment: Thx to Moonboots suggestion for T-pose, the issue has been resolved.  Thx man.  Please kindly advise any other tips that comes to mind.